# Print a string multiple times in bash based on condition

Tags: bash, azure, for-loop, command-line-interface, echo

This will list all the virtual networks in all the resource groups. A resource group can have multiple vnets. In that case i need to print the value of the resource group of every vnet. Currently i am getting the values of one to many as the result

```
rgNames=$(az group list --subscription <sub-name> --query [].name --output tsv)
for i in $rgNames; do
    vnet="$(az network vnet list -g $i --subscription <sub-name> --query [].name --output tsv)"
    echo $i,$vnet
done
```

Actual result

```
rg1,vnet1
rg2,vnet2 vnet3 vnet4
rg3,vnet5 vnet6
```

Expected result

```
rg1,vnet1
rg2,vnet2
rg2,vnet3
rg2,vnet4
rg3,vnet5
rg3,vnet6
```

Need the resource group names to be printed multiple times if it has multiple vnets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over each `vnet` as well.

```
rgNames=$(az group list --subscription <sub-name> --query [].name --output tsv)

for i in $rgNames; do
    vnets="$(az network vnet list -g $i --subscription <sub-name> --query [].name --output tsv)"

    for vnet in $vnets; do
      echo "$i,$vnet"
    done
done
```

Also: Always doublequote variables to prevent globbing, word splitting etcc.